# Access Denied Message VBA

Tags: vba

I wrote a macro to open the excel files in one folder one by one and search keywords within each of the file. However, I have no access to one of the files. So an error message saying 'Access Denied. Contact your adminstrator' came out when the macro was tring to open that file. So I need to mannually click ok to make the macro continue running.

Just want to know if any way that can make the macro skip that file. Currently way as below can not stop the error messeage coming out.

```
On Error Resume Next
    Workbooks.Open Filename:=path.Value, ReadOnly:=True, UpdateLinks:=False, Password:="****"
    If Err <> 0 Then
       For intCount = LBound(strArray) To UBound(strArray)
       ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(6 + j, 4 + intCount) = "Can't Open File"
       Next
    GoTo Label2
    Else
```

Comment: does password not match?

Comment: not password issue..just do not have access to that file. just don't want to see the error message..when meet this kind of file, want it to be ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells(6 + j, 4 + intCount) = "Can't Open File"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the top of the sub

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

Not sure if this will resolve, but would be the first thing i try if i were in this situation

Comment: No problem @user3890856. be sure to click the tick to the left of this answer to mark this answer as completed.